# How to add multiple current positions in Jobs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I want to fix my Jobs profile. I can't add multiple positions.

- I'm a full stack full time Java and Angular developer at a company
- Contractor for another company
- And I started two other small companies with friends.

I'm looking to stop doing all of the above and start working for a company abroad whenever I see a good position. I have no idea how to list multiple current positions though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a new position at an organisation, for the duration/dates; just click the checkbox "current position". You can have multiple such checkboxes selected across various companies.

[image]

---

I tested it by adding dummy values to my profile

[image: no freehand red circles]

<sub>sorry for no freehand circles</sub>

Comment: Last time i did that, the other job disappeared and the latest input became the default one. I think i can only add one

Comment: @Lynob Check the screenshot I added from my own profile.